# Is it possible to make a selection in Microsoft Paint beyond the current screen resolution?

Tags: windows-xp, selection, microsoft-paint

Is it possible to make a selection in [Microsoft Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_%28software%29) larger than the current screen resolution?

Working with full screen screenshots (including across multiple screens) is not easy in Microsoft Paint as there appears to be no way to extend a selection or making it larger than the current view while making it.

Doing menu *Edit* / *Select All* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) will make the selection cover the entire image / picture, but I need to make smaller selections than that.

Platform: Windows XP SP3

Comment: I can't say "No" conclusively, but No.

Can you download Paint.NET or GIMP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While selecting an area by holding down the left mouse button and dragging, you can use your mouse scroll wheel to scroll up and down the image. This allows using a selection larger than the screen resolution in the vertical direction.

However, you cannot scroll left to right and would probably need to zoom in/out for this.

Comment: That actually works! It is the vertical direction that really matters, so this solves the problem.

Comment: I have tried to make it clearer (I first read it as a need to hold down the left shift key, not the mouse left button). Feel free to revert or provide a different version.

Comment: Rotate image 90degrees, to work around the horizontal only scroll, then rotate back :/

Comment: also see @bruh's answer to this question: https://superuser.com/a/1697819/10663

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, not directly. However, there's still the workaround of saving a copy of the image and cropping the copy to the size you want, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. ;-)

Fwiw, newer versions of Paint include the option of zooming out, which should help in your case, but I don't know if I should recommend you to upgrade. Give it a try anyway, if you can, and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else on this earth still uses paint, after years of painful struggle zooming in and out to artificially scroll, i've finally found the holy grail: indeed you can scroll sideways while selecting, what you have to do is press ctrl + arrow keys and the screen will slowly but surely scroll to the direction you wanna go. Happy selecting!

Answer (score 0):

Zoom out with the mouse scroll wheel to a lower percent/ slider at the bottom. Then apply the crop area.

Comment: Do you really expect the Windows XP version to have that feature?

Comment: Confirming if XP does or does not have the feature would have been a more useful comment.